# Getting error on getting the sequence file content with rdd.collect() where as with rdd.foreach(println) not getting error in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to save some data into sequence file and again read the same data and trying to print it as a small exercise. I am able to see the data when i use rdd.foreach(println) but getting error when i do rdd.collect(). What exactly will happen in both the cases. In second case error is "object not serializable". I am running these commands in Spark REPL. My spark version is 1.5.1

## Sequence files saving:-

```
val data = sc.parallelize(List(("Hadoop", 1), ("Spark", 2), ("Kafka", 3)))
data.saveAsSequenceFile("file:///home/user/outputfiles/seqFileDemo1")
```

=================

## Sequence files reading:-

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{Text, IntWritable} 
val data1 = sc.sequenceFile("file:///home/user/outputfiles/seqFileDemo1", classOf[Text], classOf[IntWritable])
data1.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
("Hadoop", 1), 
("Spark", 2), 
("Kafka", 3)




scala> data1.collect()
```

Output:

```
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at <console>:19
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 5 (collect at <console>:19) with 2 output partitions
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 5(collect at <console>:19)
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 5 (file:///home/srini/Desktop/SeqFileData/ HadoopRDD[3] at sequenceFile at <console>:16), which has no missing parents
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2440) called with curMem=694040, maxMem=556038881
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_7 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.4 KB, free 529.6 MB)
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(1448) called with curMem=696480, maxMem=556038881
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_7_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1448.0 B, free 529.6 MB)
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_7_piece0 in memory on localhost:60094 (size: 1448.0 B, free: 530.2 MB)
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 7 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:861
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 5 (file:///home/srini/Desktop/SeqFileData/ HadoopRDD[3] at sequenceFile at <console>:16)
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 5.0 with 2 tasks
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 10, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2156 bytes)
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 11, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2156 bytes)
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 11)
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 10)
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/srini/Desktop/SeqFileData/part-00000:0+104
17/02/14 16:56:33 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 11)
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, value: Hadoop)
    - field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _1, type: class java.lang.Object)
    - object (class scala.Tuple2, (Hadoop,1))
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Lscala.Tuple2;, size 1)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:240)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/srini/Desktop/SeqFileData/part-00001:0+121
17/02/14 16:56:33 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 10)
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, value: Kafka)
    - field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _1, type: class java.lang.Object)
    - object (class scala.Tuple2, (Kafka,3))
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Lscala.Tuple2;, size 2)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:240)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
17/02/14 16:56:33 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 11) had a not serializable result: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, value: Hadoop)
    - field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _1, type: class java.lang.Object)
    - object (class scala.Tuple2, (Hadoop,1))
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Lscala.Tuple2;, size 1); not retrying
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 5
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 5 was cancelled
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 5 (collect at <console>:19) failed in 0.022 s
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 5 failed: collect at <console>:19, took 0.083701 s
17/02/14 16:56:33 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 10) had a not serializable result: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, value: Kafka)
    - field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _1, type: class java.lang.Object)
    - object (class scala.Tuple2, (Kafka,3))
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Lscala.Tuple2;, size 2); not retrying
17/02/14 16:56:33 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 5.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 11) had a not serializable result: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, value: Hadoop)
    - field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _1, type: class java.lang.Object)
    - object (class scala.Tuple2, (Hadoop,1))
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Lscala.Tuple2;, size 1)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1496)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1447)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1822)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1835)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1848)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1919)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:905)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:904)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:19)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:26)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:28)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:30)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:32)
    at <init>(<console>:34)
    at .<init>(<console>:38)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Text` and `IntWritable` aren't serializable. When you call `collect()`, it tries to serialize all the data and send it back to the driver. To make that work, you'll first need to extract `Text` and `IntWritable` to `String` and `Int` respectively which can be serialized:

```
val result =
  sc
   .sequenceFile[Text, IntWritable]("file:///home/user/outputfiles/seqFileDemo1")
   .map(tup => (tup._1.toString, tup._2.get()))
   .collect()
```

Comment: Thanks @Yuval . It solved my problem. Also i want to understand one thing here is that **data1** rdd created first successfully. But when i am trying to read the rdd, **data1.foreach(println)** shows the output where as **data1.collect()** is giving error. Any reason for that?